# NoSuchElementException: Cannot locate an element using XPath

Tags: automated-testing, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, exception

I am getting XPath error. Already tried with many XPath's. But not able to resolve. Can anyone give correct XPath?

XML:

```
<form id="report-filter-form" class="report-filter-form" accept-charset="utf-8" method="post" autocomplete="on" action="https://nextgen.retrofit.qa.binaryfountain.com/ng/reports/hca/practice-performance-report">
<div class="form-body white-background">
<div class="row">
<input id="top_avatar" class="form-control input-md filter-top-avatar practice-performance-report" type="hidden" value="41730" name="top_avatar"/>
<div class="col-md-12 multiple-location-avatar">
<div class="form-group ">
<label class="" for="avatar_id">Select Location(s)</label>
<div id="s2id_avatar_id" class="select2-container select2-container-multi select2 filter-avatar-id multiple-location-avatar practice-performance-report valid form-control input-md">
<ul class="select2-choices">
<li class="select2-search-field">
<label class="select2-offscreen" for="s2id_autogen5">Select Location(s)</label>

    <!-- DESIRED ELEMENT -->
    <input id="s2id_autogen5" class="select2-input select2-default" type="text" spellcheck="false" autocapitalize="off" autocorrect="off" autocomplete="off" style="width: 617px;" placeholder=""/>
    <!-- DESIRED ELEMENT -->

</li>
</ul>
<div class="select2-drop select2-drop-multi select2-display-none">
</div>
<select id="avatar_id" class="select2 select2-multiple filter-avatar-id multiple-location-avatar practice-performance-report valid form-control input-md select2-offscreen" value="" 0="excel_config_status" placeholder="Select Location(s)" label="Select Location(s)" multiple="multiple" block_class="col-md-12 multiple-location-avatar" name="avatar_id[]" tabindex="-1">
</div>
</div>
```

Highlighted path I need correct XPath. Already tried with many input XPath's and sibling XPath's.

Error Message:

```
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException:
```

Comment: share HTML screenshot

Answer (score 2):

The `id` of the `input` element looks *auto-generated* - you probably cannot use it to locate the element directly.

There are so many ways to get to the element, but I think, using the label's text and then using the [`following-sibling` axis](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Axes/following-sibling) is one of the most explicit approaches:

```
//label[. = 'Select Location(s)']/following-sibling::input
```